# Passing variable along Chtml button in Yii

Tags: php, yii, yii-chtml

Iam trying to pass variable along with Chtml button in Yii using the following code

```
 echo CHtml::button('Update', array('submit' => array('serviceRequest/Update',array('id'=>$requestId))));
```

But it is showing 404 error due to the url problem. On clicking some dummy characters is getting added to the "*id*" .
  On clicking the button Iam getting the following url. `../serviceRequest/Update/0%5Bid%5D/4` . How to remove this special characters and how can I get the correct url as `../serviceRequest/Update/id/4` . I need button itself there..
 Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
array('submit' => $this->createUrl('serviceRequest/Update',array('id'=>$requestId)))
```

Comment: On applying the above change the url now showing is ../ServiceRequest/Invites">serviceRequest/Update</a>